# How to have wget only follow a small set of paths

Tags: wget

Trying to get wget to handle a sort of complicated situation. Basically I want it to only allow files/folders that fit this system:

```
https://example.com/top/a-file
https://example.com/top/a-file.ext
https://example.com/top/nested/directory/one.ext
https://example.com/top/another/nested/dir/two?maybe=paramsToo
```

I don't want it to follow paths like these:

```
https://example.com/
https://example.com/a-file
https://example.com/a-file.ext
https://example.com/top/
https://example.com/top/directory/
https://example.com/top/directory/one.ext
https://example.com/top/another/deeply/nested/direct/two?maybe=paramsToo
```

Basically, I only want it to handle this:

```
/top/:file
/top/nested/directory/:file
/top/another/nested/dir/:file
```

Those specific paths are allowed.

Within those paths, I want to also only allow specific files (.html, .js, .css, or no extension).

What I tried is this:

wget --no-parent -r -R .zip,.tar,.gz,.jpg https://example.com/top

This partially works, except in this situation: when it is currently evaluating this page:

```
https://example.com/top/nested/directory/one.ext
```

...and that page links here:

```
https://example.com/top/a-file
```

...the `--no-parent` option prevents it from going up to the parent. What I wanted the `--no-parent` option to do was just not allow going above `/top`, but instead it seems to be *relative to the currently evaluating page*, which doesn't make sense.

I know about `-X` to exclude specific folders/paths, but I don't know all the possible paths it may encounter so I don't know what to exclude.

So wondering how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how it's redirecting you to https://example.com/top/a-file, have you tried using

```
    --max-redirect 0
```